# Database: backup few tables with data+schema and other tables with only schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

In our database, we have application related data tables and transaction related data tables. since there is huge amount of records in my transaction table I want to ignore them while taking backup. So basically when I run a scheduler I want schema + data for application related tables and only schema for transaction related data tables. 
I was suggested to use generate script. however I'm not sure if it would work because my application tables are linked with each other and my primary key columns are generally identity columns.

Comment: You should create separate a filegroup for your application tables. Then you should backup only that newly created file group.

Comment: For such scenario, a regular SQL Server Backup functionality will not work at all, because there is no way to split data and structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> backup few tables with data+schema and other tables with only schema

For such a scenario, a regular SQL Server Backup functionality will not work at all, because there is no way to split data and structure and no way to avoid backup of some tables.

Even if you will perform a filegroup backup, it does not mean that you can restore only that filegroup and leave other tables as is. The filegroup backups just do not work this way.

Therefore, scripting can be one of the solutions:

- 1. Create a script of data and structure for smaller tables
- 2. Create a script of the structure only of transactional tables

---

Another approach is a dump necessary data and structure into a separate database with a further backup:

Something like:

```
SELECT * INTO ExportDB.dbo.Table1
SELECT * INTO ExportDB.dbo.Table2
SELECT * INTO ExportDB.dbo.Table3
--- two tables below will  have no data, only a structure
SELECT * INTO ExportDB.dbo.Table4 WHERE 1=0 -- A large transactional table 1
SELECT * INTO ExportDB.dbo.Table5 WHERE 1=0 -- A large Transactional table 1

BACKUP DATABASE ExportDB TO DISK='..'
DROP DATABASE ExportDB
```

However, native backups (that are not an option for your scenario) can ensure data consistency, enforced by PK and FK, while custom options I mentioned after, cannot really guarantee it

References:
[How can I take backup of particular tables in SQL Server 2008 using T-SQL Script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102745/how-can-i-take-backup-of-particular-tables-in-sql-server-2008-using-t-sql-script)

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Since I'm using identity in PK column backup through script is not an option. Maintaining data consistency by PK and FK is must for me. I could think of taking a full backup of source DB and deleting transactional tables. but is there a way to automate this process - backup > delete > backup ??

Comment: The flow of automation then: take a full backup -> restore it side-by-side (on another server?) -> truncate large transactional tables -> take a full backup of cleaned db -> remove cleaned db